# Selecting most recently changed reactive expressions in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a reactive expression, the value of which I want to take from whichever of two other reactive expressions has been changed most recently. I've made the following example:

ui.r:

```
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
column(4, wellPanel(
  actionButton("button", "Button"),
  checkboxGroupInput("check", "Check", choices = c("a", "b", "c"))
)),
column(8,
  textOutput("test")
)
))
```

And server.r:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
 output$test <- renderText({
  # Solution goes here
 })
})
```

I would like for the output to show the value of either `button` (the number of times the button has been clicked) *or* `check` (a character vector showing which boxes are checked) *depending* on which was changed most recently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this using `reactiveValues` to keep track of the current state of button presses:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(ui = shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  column(4, wellPanel(
    actionButton("button", "Button"),
    checkboxGroupInput("check", "Check", choices = c("a", "b", "c"))
  )),
  column(8,
         textOutput("test")
  )
))
, server = function(input, output, session){
  myReactives <- reactiveValues(reactInd = 0)
  observe({
    input$button
    myReactives$reactInd <- 1
  })
  observe({
    input$check
    myReactives$reactInd <- 2
  })
  output$test <- renderText({
    if(myReactives$reactInd == 1){
      return(input$button)
    }
    if(myReactives$reactInd == 2){
      return(input$check)
    }
  })
}
)
)
```

[image]