# R Shiny How can I determine the most recently modified reactive expression when one modifies the other?

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, reactive-programming

Basically I have a hierarchy of multi-select inputs, call them a, b and c, with size(a) > size(b) > size(c). Every unit of b belongs to a unit of a, and every unit of c belongs to a unit of b. When you remove something from a, it removes the corresponding things from b, which in turn removes the corresponding things from c.

What I need to do, is determine which multi-select input the user last modified. I followed this result here [Selecting most recently changed reactive expressions in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672304/selecting-most-recently-changed-reactive-expressions-in-shiny) but it doesn't work because if I were to modify a, it would then modify b and then c, and the result would be that the program thinks the user modified c.

My question is then, is there a way to differentiate user input from regular update calls?

A second question might be is there a way to determine ahead of time the order that reactive expressions will resolve? I've noticed for example that if I remove a lot of values from a or b, it will resolve the removal of these values one a time and then continue on to remove the values from the lower hierarchy. I previously expected that it would alternate (remove from b, remove corresponding from c, remove from b, remove corresponding from c etc.) but that's not the case.

Here is an example, you can run the code and you'll see when you edit the one or two selection it will quickly flash "one" or "two" but it will always reset to "three". An exception is when you remove the last item in the list which will not update the levels below it for some reason.

```
library("shiny")
one = vector(mode="list", length = 4)
names(one) = c("a","b","c","d")
two = vector(mode="list", length = 8)
names(two) = c("e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l")
three = vector(mode="list", length = 16)
three = c("m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","aa","ab")
one[["a"]] = c("e","f")
one[["b"]] = c("g","h")
one[["c"]] = c("i","j")
one[["d"]] = c("k","l")
two[["e"]] = c("m","n")
two[["f"]] = c("o","p")
two[["g"]] = c("q","r")
two[["h"]] = c("s","t")
two[["i"]] = c("u","v")
two[["j"]] = c("w","x")
two[["k"]] = c("y","z")
two[["l"]] = c("aa", "ab")
ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Example"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("selectOne", label="Select One:", choices=names(one), selected = names(one), multiple=TRUE),
            selectInput("selectTwo", label="Select Two:", choices=names(two), selected = names(two), multiple=TRUE),
            selectInput("selectThree", label="Select Three:", choices=three, multiple=TRUE),
            actionButton("reset",label = "Reset")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            textOutput("listOfThree"),
            textOutput("lastUpdated"),
            textOutput("updated")
        )
    )
)

server = shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

    output$listOfThree = renderText({
        paste("list of three:", paste(input$selectThree, collapse = ", "), sep = " ")
    })
    output$lastUpdated = renderText({
        paste("last update:",rv$lastUpdate, sep = " ")
    })
    rv = reactiveValues(lastUpdate = "four")
    observe({
        oneList = input$selectOne
        rv$lastUpdate = "one"
        twoList = c()
        for (thing in oneList){
            twoList = c(twoList, one[[thing]])
        }
        twoList = sort(twoList)
        updateSelectInput(session, "selectTwo", selected = twoList)

    })
    observe({
        twoList = input$selectTwo
        rv$lastUpdate = "two"
        threeList = c()
        for (thing in twoList){
            threeList = c(threeList, two[[thing]])
        }
        threeList = sort(threeList)
        updateSelectInput(session, "selectThree", selected = threeList)

    })
    observe({
        input$selectThree
        rv$lastUpdate = "three"
    })
    observeEvent(
        input$reset,
        {
            updateSelectInput(session, "selectOne", selected = names(one))
            updateSelectInput(session, "selectTwo", selected = names(two))
            updateSelectInput(session, "selectThree", selected = three)
            rv$updateTwo = FALSE
            rv$updateThree = FALSE
        }
    )
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: sample code please?  Without sample code it is near to impossible to understand what you mean.  It does seem to me that you  are dangerously trying to use a tool designed in principle to be stateless (thanks to reactivity) in a stateful way.

Comment: I have added an example. Could you go more in depth about stateful and statelessness and why it's dangerous?